# При авторизации на сайт или админ-панель ошибка 500 JFolder::сreate: Infinite loop detected

Tags: joomla, cms

Всем привет! Я работаю на `Joomla 2.5`

База данных одна (локальная и сайт). Я работаю через `FTP - FileZilla`.

При авторизации на сайте или в админ-панель (пустые поля или неправильно заполненные) выдается ошибка `500 JFolder::сreate: Infinite loop detected`.

Ошибка: http://prntscr.com/m07hqb.

Я просмотрел каждый файл, синтаксических ошибок нет.

Локальные и на сайте configuration.php одинаковые файлы. http://prntscr.com/m0e13l

Но в локальной сети без 00 ошибок все работает хорошо. И ошибки перестали попадать в `/logs/error.php`. Я зарегистрировал полный путь и дал права доступа к `777`. В админке написано, что доступа нет.

Права доступа на каталог http://prntscr.com/m0b9i0

Глобальные настройки в админ-панели:

http://prntscr.com/m0b9u3 | http://prntscr.com/m0ba2s | http://prntscr.com/m0b97k

FTP -FileZilla http://prntscr.com/m0bagv

Comment: А версии ПО одинаковые? Ну там php например

Comment: @Nilsan  Local: Версия PHP 5.5.38. Site: Версия PHP 5.6.39

Comment: Попробуйте для начала ваше окружение настроить чтоб были одинаковые версии